# Laravel 5 deleting product image when entire category is deleted

Tags: php, laravel, relationship

I have two tables: categories and products.

In products table migration I have defined this:

```
$table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
```

so when a category is deleted, all products from that category is deleted.

Model for category contains:

```
public function product() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Model for product contains:

```
public function category() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
}
```

Category and product model contains two methods for saving and deleting photos, that are stored on file system.

Method for deleting the photo attached to category or photo:

```
public static function deleteImage($id) {
    File::deleteDirectory(public_path() . self::$imagesPath . $id);
}
```

This method is called by overriding destroy function on product or category model:

```
 public static function destroy($id) {
    self::deleteImage($id);
    parent::destroy($id);
}
```

So, the problem is if I delete a category, I want to delete products images too, beside records in products table, but products images remain on the file system. Only category images are deleted from the file system.

I put an dd('message') in destroy function in product model, but seems that the destroy method, on product model is not called when a category is deleted.

How can I delete product images, when a category is deleted?

Comment: Products  deletion will be done from mysql side (in case of innodb), not laravel, so you need to run an event before delete   categories to iterate  over all products related  to the categories and remove them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since MySQL is the one deleting the products, Eloquent has no way to know about it.

You'll have to do it in the category model's `deleting` event:

```
class Category extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot()
    {
        static::deleting(function()
        {
            foreach ($this->products as $product)
            {
                $product->deleteImage($product->id);
            }
        });
    }

}
```